# Hashmap. Find key(s) which have same values between two hashmaps

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Lets consider we have two hashmaps as below:

```
 HashMap<String, Integer> map1  = new HashMap<>(); 
 map1.put("vishal", 10); 
 map1.put("sachin", 30); 
 map1.put("vaibhav", 20); 

 HashMap<String, Integer> map2  = new HashMap<>(); 
 map2.put("Raja", 10); 
 map2.put("John", 30); 
 map2.put("Krishna", 20);
```

The "vaibhav" from map1 and "krishna" from map2 have the same values.

I need to find the keys from both the maps, which have the same values. In this case, "vaibhav" and "Krishna".

Thanks.

Comment: "I need" is not a question. Please see [ask].

Comment: You may consider to add the output for this sample input.

Comment: You can `groupBy` values and then map keys into a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve the time complexity to `O(n + m)` where `n` is the size of first map and `m` is the size of the second map.

- We can achieve this by making `values` as keys and `keys` as values.
- Steps:

  - Iterate over each map.
  - Store all current map values in a new map and collect all keys who have that value in a list and put the current value with this list in the new map.
  - Now, iterate over any of the new map collections and get the common keys and it's respective values for printing.

**Snippet:**

```
private static void showCommonValueKeys(HashMap<String, Integer> map1,HashMap<String, Integer> map2){
    Map<Integer,List<String>> map1Collect = flipKeyValue(map1);
    Map<Integer,List<String>> map2Collect = flipKeyValue(map2);

    for(Map.Entry<Integer,List<String>> m : map1Collect.entrySet()){
        int key = m.getKey();
        if(map2Collect.containsKey(key)){
            System.out.println("For value " + key);
            System.out.println("First map keys: " + m.getValue().toString());
            System.out.println("Second map keys: " + map2Collect.get(key).toString());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}

private static  Map<Integer,List<String>> flipKeyValue(HashMap<String, Integer> map){
     Map<Integer,List<String>> mapCollect = new HashMap<>(); 

     for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> m : map.entrySet()){
        String  key = m.getKey();
        int val = m.getValue();
        mapCollect.putIfAbsent(val,new ArrayList<>());
        mapCollect.get(val).add(key);
     }

     return mapCollect;
}
```

**Demo:** https://onlinegdb.com/SJdcpbOXU

Answer (score 3):

Group by values and store keys in list:

```java
Stream.of(map1.entrySet(), map2.entrySet())
.flatMap(Collection::stream)
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        Collectors.mapping(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.toList()
        )
));
```

It will create:

```
{20=[vaibhav, Krishna], 10=[vishal, Raja], 30=[sachin, John]}
```

#### UPDATE

Other approach

```java
Map<Integer, List<String>> collect = new HashMap<>();
map1.entrySet().forEach(e -> collect
        .computeIfAbsent(e.getValue(), k -> new ArrayList<>())
        .add(e.getKey()));
map2.entrySet().forEach(e -> collect
        .computeIfAbsent(e.getValue(), k -> new ArrayList<>())
        .add(e.getKey()));
```

Comment: @ManojBanik the time complexity is `O( n + m)`, where `n` and 'm' are sizes of list. It can be written in other way.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through two for loops with a complexity of n*m, where n.m is the size of each map.

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("santhosh", "1");
map1.put("raja", "2");
map1.put("arun", "3");


Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("kumar", "1");
map2.put("mani", "1");
map2.put("tony", "3");

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 : map1.entrySet()) {
  String key1 = entry1.getKey();
  String value1 = entry1.getValue();

  for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry2 : map2.entrySet()) {
    String key2 = entry2.getKey();
    String value2 = entry2.getValue();

    if (value1 == value2) {
      System.out.println(key1 + " " + key2);
    }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are many ways, here are some as reference: https://www.baeldung.com/java-compare-hashmaps

Comment: [Don’t compare strings using `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/2711488)

Comment: You can improve the time complexity. Can values duplicate inside a single map?